# How to switch off the sounds?

Tags: bell

Those sounds all the way drive me crazy, but it is uncomfortable to switch off system sounds at all because I need them in other places same time. I didn't find any settings where I could manage the sounds.

Comment: I assume you mean the annoying bell sound in emacs. If that's the case, you can disable it by adding this in your `.emacs` :

`(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)`

Comment: @ChakravarthyRaghunandan sorry, but I didn't find this file, could you give a hint?

Comment: o my god YES, I found it because I forgot to setup the folder for search and it searched through all the disks. It helped, thanx a lot!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Turn off the bell, use the visual bell instead, or replace bell-ringing by some other visual indication.

You can set `ring-bell-function` to a function such as `ignore`, to just turn off all indication.

Or you can customize option [`visible-bell`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Display-Custom.html), to use a frame flash instead of a sound.

Or you can use minor mode `echo-bell-mode` from library [`echo-bell.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/echo-bell.el) to get just a brief visual indication in the echo area.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Beeping](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Beeping.html).

Comment: but where to do it? I do not see any hint nor here neither by the link, I'm missing some base knowledge everybody knows

Comment: You can put variable settings in your [init file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) (and see [Find Init](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html)), and you can turn on a minor mode there. The Emacs manual (`C-h r`) is your friend. A little time spent there can really help you wrt base knowledge, and a lifetime spent there can be a great pastime. ;-)

Comment: I try to follow the instructions in @find file@, but I have no HOME enviroment vaiable (what makes sence, I have never set up HOME), and I also can't find init file by it's name by total commande's "find". Could it have a name like "ediff-init.el" or "viper-init.el"?

Comment: ok, I'm in helh menue or somethig got there by C-h r, but where there to find anything relates to my problem?

Comment: should I write this init file from the scratch?

Comment: `C-h r` takes you to the *Emacs* manual. To use the manual, you would do well to first do **`C-h i`** and choose the ***Info*** manual - that will tell you *how to use the manuals* from within Emacs.

Comment: You can use **`C-x C-f ~/.emacs`** to create an init file. But first read about the init file a bit.

Comment: @AnnaLeonenko just put the following lines in your `~/.emacs` file: `(setq visible-bell t)` and `(setq ring-bell-function 'ignore)`. You will also need to restart your emacs or eval the file.

Comment: I usually set things up with customize. I.e. you do 'M-x describe-variable ENTER ring-bell-function` then you can go to a menu where you can select silent.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile Emacs yourself, and you don't want it to be capable of producing sound in general, then you can use:

```
./configure --without-sound
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of turning off sound, you can use a visible-bell,

this function temporarily inverts the mode-line/header-line

```el
(defun my-mode-line-visual-bell ()
  (setq visible-bell nil)
  (setq ring-bell-function 'my-mode-line-visual-bell--flash))

(defun my-mode-line-visual-bell--flash ()
  (let ((frame (selected-frame)))
    (run-with-timer
     0.1 nil
     #'(lambda (frame)
         (let ((inhibit-quit)
               (inhibit-redisplay t))
           (invert-face 'header-line frame)
           (invert-face 'header-line-highlight frame)
           (invert-face 'mode-line frame)
           (invert-face 'mode-line-inactive frame)))
     frame)
    (let ((inhibit-quit)
          (inhibit-redisplay t))
      (invert-face 'header-line frame)
      (invert-face 'header-line-highlight frame)
      (invert-face 'mode-line frame)
      (invert-face 'mode-line-inactive frame))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add line below to your `.emacs.d/init.cl` file or any other startup file:

```el
(set-message-beep 'silent)
```

For more information on this topic look at help docs for `set-message-beep` via command `C-h f` followed by `set-message-beep`

This question are addresses in `Emacs W32 FAQ > Display Settings > Beep Sound`

Comment: n.b. this function is implemented for the MS Windows build only.